# Flutter - Firebase callable functions with region not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

we currently facing the problem in our flutter app, that httpsCallable functions which are defined with a region, in our case "europe-west1", is throwing an exception:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object.

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35:37)
<asynchronous suspension>

#0      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:39:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:35:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

As far, as we tested, it makes no difference, if we define the region in flutter accordingly to [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage/#specifying-regions):

```
final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1').httpsCallable('myCallableFunction').call();
```

Or directly in the cloud function:

```
exports.myCallableFunction = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall((data, context) => {
   // ... return result
});
```

If we remove the region on both lines above, the callable function is working and returning the expected result.

Is there something, what I miss or is there currently an issue in flutter itself?

Comment: You need both, in Cloud Functions and in Flutter. Have you re-deployed your functions after this change?

Comment: This works for me for the Node.js part: `const functions = require("firebase-functions").region('europe-west3');` and then: `exports.something = functions.https.onCall...`. Dart side I have the same as yours.

Comment: Go and check what is the response of the endpoint result, print it. Then you will probably know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some testing and the comment from Peter Koltai, the solution is defining the region in both, flutter and cloud functions:

flutter:

```
final result = await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west1').httpsCallable('myCallableFunction').call();
```

cloud functions:

```
exports.myCallableFunction = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onCall((data, context) => {
   // ... return result
});
```

Of course, this makes sense, because as the caller, I want to call the callable functions out of the "europe-west1" region. This gives, if required, the flexibility to call different functions for different regions.

Comment: One more thing to add here if your are using emulator don't forgot to 
mention region in both initialization and calling, otherwise it will call default us-central

FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);

await FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west2').httpsCallable('testFun3').call();